# Django - Form Validation not showing

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a registration page with the following code below:

in the views:

```
def register_step2(request, value):
context={"type": value}
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        nric = form.cleaned_data['nric']
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        phonenumber = form.cleaned_data['phonenumber']
        dob = form.cleaned_data['dob']
        User.objects.create_user(nric, email, password)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
return render_to_response('register.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```

in the register.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block subheader %}
{% if type == '0' %}
Are you..
{% endif %}
{% if type == '1' %}
Registration - Able Elder
{% endif %}
{% if type == '2' %}
Registration - Public
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if type == '0' %}
<a href="/register/1">an elderly looking for something to do?</a>
<a href="/register/2">the public looking for someone to help you?</a>
{% else %}
<form action="/register/{{type}}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table class="center">
{% for field in able_form %}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ field.label_tag }}: 
    </td>
    <td>
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field }}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr>
<td>
{{ able_form.non_field_errors }} 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
By clicking on "register" I agree with the terms and conditions.
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
</td>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

in context_processors.py (it is setup properly in settings.py )

```
from forms import RegisterForm

def able_form(request):
    return {
            'able_form' : RegisterForm()}
```

in the forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    nric = forms.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    postal_code = forms.IntegerField()
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField()
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput)
```

It is to my understanding that the variable fields will display the field errors, but none is shown when I click on the register button. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i don't see a form being passed to the template context at all.. where is `able_form` coming from?

Comment: the form can be displayed properly. I'll update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your update, the reason is obvious:

You are only ever passing a blank form to your template.

Where do you assume that the bound form with `request.POST` data gets returned to your template? Creating a new instance of `RegisterForm(request.POST)` does not magically change the form instance in your template (returned by the context processor).

Your template only ever sees `RegisterForm()` -- if it is to know of a form error, it must have the form that was bound with the request.POST data.

```
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       ....
    context['able_form'] = form # you must pass back the bound form if you want to see errors.
return render_to_response('register.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```

Even then, your context processor may override this `able_form` key - I'd remove the context processor altogether.

If you think it's a great idea to have it, then you have to remember to do your form logic there or in your view.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it. I left the context processor there and it still works perfectly fine. :) I forgot to pass the bound form back to the context..

Comment: Yuji - thx, both for the answer and logic - i was having same problem but now understand why.